# 80's fantasy trilogy about where main character was paralyzed in the real world, but was able to walk in the magical fantasy world

Tags: story-identification

I read a fantasy trilogy back in the early 80's and looking for its title.

The main character was paralyzed in the real world, but was able to walk in the magical fantasy world he was transported to. The fantasy world was a bit comical. His first encounter in this world was with a centaur that harassed people on the road. The centaur's name was Chester, hence the title Chester the molester.
Later on in his journey he came across a bodyguard that was virtually indestructible. I think he was an outcast "Bloodguard". The thief book had a picture of a hilly forest scene, and I think the title was something like Cottage under the hill, or something like that.

Comment: Interesting, you might also want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: The Xanth books by Piers Anthony have a centaur called Chester, who is known to be quick to anger. There are 40+ books in the series, but none of them have "Cottage" in the title. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth

Comment: Thanks for the assist..I think you hit it with the Xanth books.